# Загрузка Stage с таблицей с данными JAVAFX

Tags: javafx, tableview

При нажатии кнопки, должен открывается Stage c таблицей, в котором есть TableView.Реализую таким образом, получаю fxml Scene, добавляю данные в таблицy TableView этой сцены, отправляю Stage.
Реализация:
Main:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static Client.NET.Client.STOP;
import static Client.NET.Client.ShowCar;
import static Client.NET.Client.getInstanceClient;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static Stage primaryStage;

    @Override
    public  void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Client/FXML/Scene1.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        runStage(primaryStage);

    }

    public static void setStage(Stage stage)
    {
        primaryStage = stage;
    }

    public static Stage getStage() {return primaryStage;}

    public static void setScene(Scene scene)
    {
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    }

    public static Scene getScene() {
        return primaryStage.getScene();
    }

    public static void runStage(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        primaryStage = stage;
        primaryStage.setTitle("ClientProgram");
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(300);
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(530);
        primaryStage.setMaxHeight(400);
        primaryStage.setMaxWidth(630);
        getInstanceClient();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller1:

```
     public void  IsAuto(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {


    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Client/FXML/ShowAuto.fxml"));
    Main.primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

    ObservableList<TableCar> Cars = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Inish());
    Marka.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableCar,String>("Markat"));
    Model.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableCar,String>("Modelt"));
    Color.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableCar,String>("Colort"));
    Color.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableCar,String>("Modelt"));
    Price.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableCar,Float>("Pricett"));
    Count.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableCar,Integer>("Countt"));
    TableCars.setItems(Cars);

    Main.primaryStage.show();
}
```

Возникают ошибки:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at Client.CONTROLLER.Controller1.IsAuto(Controller1.java:116)
... 58 more
```

Происходит смена Stage, однако таблица пустая. Думаю, что проблема в правильности взаимодействия добавления данных в таблицу и сменой Stage.

Класс TableCar:

```
    public class TableCar {
private String markat;
private String modelt;
private String colort;
private String yeart;
private float pricet;
private int countt;


public String getMarkat() {
    return markat;
}

public void setMarkat(String markat) {
    this.markat = markat;
}

public String getModelt() {
    return modelt;
}

public void setModelt(String modelt) {
    this.modelt = modelt;
}

public String getColort() {
    return colort;
}

public void setColort(String colort) {
    this.colort = colort;
}

public String getYeart() {
    return yeart;
}

public void setYeart(String yeart) {
    this.yeart = yeart;
}

public float getPricet() {
    return pricet;
}

public void setPricet(float pricet) {
    this.pricet = pricet;
}

public int getCountt() {
    return countt;
}

public void setCountt(int countt) {
    this.countt = countt;
}
```

}

Метод Inish():

```
       public ArrayList Inish()
{
    ArrayList<Goods> arrayList = ShowCar();//ShowCar - возвращает ArrayList c данными
    ArrayList<TableCar> tableCars = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i<arrayList.size();i++)
    {
        TableCar tableCar = new TableCar();
        tableCar.setMarkat(arrayList.get(i).getCar().getMarka());
        tableCar.setModelt(arrayList.get(i).getCar().getModel());
        tableCar.setColort(arrayList.get(i).getCar().getColor());
        tableCar.setYeart(arrayList.get(i).getCar().getYear());
        tableCar.setPricet(arrayList.get(i).getPrice());
        tableCar.setCountt(arrayList.get(i).getCount());
        tableCars.add(tableCar);
    }
    System.out.println("Проверка:" + tableCars.size());
    return  tableCars;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48454/discussion-on-question-by-bsuart2017--stage-----javafx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение проблемы: Для сцены с TableView должен быть определен свой собственный контроллер, этот класс должен реализовать интерфейс implements Initializable, и в методе

```
   @Override
   public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){}
```

Должно быть определено чем будет заполняться таблица, данный метод вызывается сразу после загрузки соответствующего fxml файла.